# React TypeScript select node contents from a ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ref

Is there a chance I can possibly feed the React `ref` to the document range `.selectNodeContents()` function. The error I end up with is:

```
Argument of type 'HTMLDivElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Node'.ts(2345)
(property) React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>.current: HTMLDivElement | null
```

My assumption is that the ref is declared before it actually was assigned, but I don't really understand how to overcome this in TypeScript. Sorry if duplicate, just didn't find it on the Internet

```js
export const Code: FC<ICode> = ({
    codeString
}) => {
    const codeRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    const clickHandler = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        let range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(codeRef.current); // <-- Error here!!
        window.getSelection()?.removeAllRanges();
        window.getSelection()?.addRange(range);

        navigator?.clipboard?.writeText(codeString);
    };

    return (
        <div
          id="Code"
          className="Code"
          onClick={clickHandler}
          ref={codeRef}
        >
            { codeString }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `codeRef.current` might be either `null` or `HTMLDivElement` whether `selectNodeContents` expects only `Node`.

All you need to do is to wrap `codeRef.current` into condition:

```js
import React, { FC, useRef } from 'react'

interface ICode {
  codeString: string
}
export const Code: FC<ICode> = ({
  codeString
}) => {
  const codeRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const clickHandler = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    let range = document.createRange();
    if (codeRef.current) {
      range.selectNodeContents(codeRef.current); // ok
      window.getSelection()?.removeAllRanges();
      window.getSelection()?.addRange(range);

      navigator?.clipboard?.writeText(codeString);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      id="Code"
      className="Code"
      onClick={clickHandler}
      ref={codeRef}
    >
      {codeString}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwtgK4DOSyAZnAL5xVQQhwDkUqGrAUN8AHYwkUKuiRwAkoQgATcTm5w4aWUgDKMKAIDmALjhlNO7rW5IAHpFjKI-Q3Glz9RADxTVAPjgBeOAAoFJRU5DS1%20bRMASh8vQJs7eGDKJBpfcmSqFwAJABUAWQAZABFgADcAUQAbJBAkQQ8-fhJKysiAbl4g23s0SuA0AGsslH4ZaqgffyR9ZHQYADo8iHTy0rqYbPzisqqa9Y9o71jFJThq%20CgR7XFfGQg0ElrBebQOFCEEK6Q-dpOlYBofiS1BeJCgHEE0Tipzgl3CSHmFGqGAAcqppIJ1mQgaoQQ9wet2nAAPTEuAuAC0FLg5XB0DgAAthEgAIQsv6nADuAjunPm1xgaiQyJgwFsPwA-PMOCAIGsAIItT7w7G-GFKbmjCB8gVCkVi-iS%20YoGQyZXXPxw66-DlKfgoUrAbTvaBS3rAMAAIwgKCgMilnK0QhyFhgOJCRnCatOpiUtA6Jw4MDB-H8HJcMjKtrgwBk3gARI4kPns70UGQyCiULUC0WS%20q4LZCH1Bt4cO7BsNRuNY%20qOFQ28CUr2lB5s%203VKEdCPycTM6Ux0pfrQgA)